# Get value of any attributes from XML data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml

```
<RDService status="NOTREADY" info="Morpho_RD_Service">
   <Interface id="CAPTURE" path="/127.0.0.1:11100/capture" />
   <Interface id="DEVICEINFO" path="/127.0.0.1:11100/getDeviceInfo" />
</RDService>
```

I have the above XML response. I want the value of status from the response. I am trying to get it by the below code:

```
$(xmlresponse).getAttributeValue('status');
```

But I am getting an exception as:
**$(...).getAttributeValue is not a function**

Comment: Indeed, `getAttributeValue()` is not a jQuery method. Where did you find this?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery method to read attributes is `.attr` https://api.jquery.com/attr/ which can be applied to xml:

```
$(xml).attr("status")
```

```js
var xml = '<RDService status="NOTREADY" info="Morpho_RD_Service">'
   +'<Interface id="CAPTURE" path="/127.0.0.1:11100/capture" />'
   +'<Interface id="DEVICEINFO" path="/127.0.0.1:11100/getDeviceInfo" />'
+'</RDService>'

console.log($(xml).attr("status"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```